# NSMutableArray prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a small problem with an app where a debug I made there must be a conflict in a `prepareForSegue`: Let me explain
I have a `UITableView` with an array of data written by me.
Then I have another array with data of a `xcdatamodel` that the user must edit and save.

if I run with this screen `prepareForSegue` me when I call a cell crashes.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailSchedule"]) {
      NSManagedObjectModel *selectedSche = [schedule objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
      DetailMainHallTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
      DetailMainHallTableViewController *dc = segue.destinationViewController;
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
      dc.mainhall = self.myArraySchedule1[indexPath.row];
      destViewController.sche = selectedSche;
    }
}
```

but if I run with this screen of the app runs `prepareForSegue` okay but I did not save the entered data

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailSchedule"]) {
       //NSManagedObjectModel *selectedSche = [schedule objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
       DetailMainHallTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       DetailMainHallTableViewController *dc = segue.destinationViewController;
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
       dc.mainhall = self.myArraySchedule1[indexPath.row];
       //destViewController.sche = selectedSche;
    }
}
```

It is strange, however, that if we take off // and I run again the data I had entered before appearing saved me and I can edit them or add them.
Can these two lines to understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `UITableView` you should move the `NSManagedObjectModel` code to the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and then send that object as the sender for your segue.